# Disallow with robots.txt specific domain ending

Tags: blogger, robots.txt, tld

I want to disallow **with robots.txt** from indexing my site available with all domain endings (co.uk, in, pl, de, nl ...etc), but allow only with com-ending.

I haven't physical access to htaccess file (affected is a blogger.com blog), otherwise i would just redirect all endings to the wishful one. But while i can't redirect, i want even to disallow all endings, beside of .com.

Sure, i could just create a list with all endings and disallow them one by one, but it seems to me, there must be a smarter solution for this issue, which i haven't found till now.

How to do that?

Comment: You realize `robots.txt` doesn't *actually prevent* viewings, but simply hints at the *relevant* bits of site information for robots to look at... right?

Comment: Yes, sure! While i can't prevent viewing through redirecting with htaccess, i want at least disallow indexing to prevent duplicated content from each domain ending.

Comment: The prefered way would be `301 Moved Permanently` header for your main domain

Comment: @ Christian: redirects aren't possible at blogger.com. Beside of this, what concretely i achieve with 301 for the main domain, and where should it be pointed in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer** for all, who is looking for:

1. **The issue can't be solved with `robots.txt`.**
2. But Blogger's default template (and other well done templates) contains a
   `rel="canonical"` tag, which points to the URL with the "main"
   domain ending and in this manner figures out the issue with
   duplicated content from domains with all other domain endings.